# Multiplication of asymptotic approximation

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, approximation-theory

If I know that:
$a = (1 - O(\frac{1}{n}))$ and $b = (1 + O(\frac{1}{n}))$, what is the asymptotic approximation of
$a\cdot b$? Is answer $ab = (1 - O(\frac{1}{n^2}))$ correct or it is still $ab = (1 - O(\frac{1}{n}))$?

Are any source, when I can find some more information about action like adding, multiplication or powering this type of approximations?

Comment: @SA-255525 clearly, it is not, as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it useful to think in term of example functions that satify the the big $O$. Try multiplying $1 - \frac{10}{n}$ with $1 + \frac{1}{n}$.
$$
\left(1 - \frac{10}{n}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) = 1-\frac{9}{n}-\frac{10}{n^2}
$$
Is this $1 - O(\frac{1}{n^2})$?

Another way is to expand the multiplication using algebraic rules. Just keep in mind that the two $O(\frac{1}{n})$ do not necessarily have to be the same function.

$$
  ab = \left(1 - O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
     = 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$

Now it is clear that you cannot really determine the result as $1 + O(\dots)$. It can either be $1 + O(\frac1n)$, $1 - O(\frac1n)$ or $1 - O(\frac1{n^2})$. You could do it if you knew which function was dominating (or if they were equal).

I assumed that the functions in big $O$ are positive and you care about the direction you are approaching 1 from.

Comment: I think it is 1 - $O(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: And you are correct. :) This particular example is $1 - O(\frac{1}{n})$. Now try it with $1 + \frac{10}{n}$ and $1 - \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: In second example I have $1 + \frac{9}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}$, so I think it is $1 + O(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Ok, so let's suppose that both are positive and I have $1+O(\frac{1}{n})-O(\frac{1}{n})-O(\frac{1}{n^2})$, and the second O(\frac{1}{n}) is 'bigger' than the first one, then the answear should be $1 - O(\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: Yes. If the second $O(\frac{1}{n})$ dominates the result will be $1 - O(\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is just
$$
a b + O(\frac{1}{n})
$$
Remember what $O()$ means. For appropriate $N_0$, whenever $n > N_0$ you have:
$$
a - \frac{c_a}{n} < a^* \le a \\
b  \le b^* < b + \frac{c_b}{n}
$$
Multiplying the inequalities gets you
$$
a b - \frac{b c_a}{n} < a^* b^* < a b + \frac{a c_b}{n}
$$